# Get Value From Double Entry Table

Tags: excel

I have the following tables:

[image]

How can I calculate values in column C3 based on the second table?

Basically, for first row I have Product = A and Quantity = 5.

So the unit price will be taken from the second table (Product = A, Quantity < 10): 4.5

So value will be 5 * 4.5 = 22,5

I am not sure but I might do this with VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cells adjacent to the reference table, put the following values:

- I3: Put 0
- I4: Put 5
- I5: Put 10
- I6: Put 15

In C3, put the formula:

```
=INDEX($F$3:$H$6,MATCH(B3,$I$3:$I$6,1),MATCH(A3,$F$2:$H$2,0))*B3
```

You can then drag it down.

If you want to use vlookup, you might go with putting the values I mentioned above in cells D3 to D6 and use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,D:H,MATCH(A3,$F$2:$H$2,0)+2)*B3
```

Comment: Wouldn't be shorter to use maybe VLookup with Match? I tried but wasn't able to make it work ...

Comment: @Shapper I forgot about vlookup when I tried to match the products, oops! But yes, it's definitely shorter! Updated answer.